# Is this sentence meaningful?

Tags: word-usage, transitivity

Is this sentence correct?

> I felt the tea hot.

Is *felt* or *feel* used like this?

Comment: It is not idiomatic. _I could feel that the tea was hot_ sounds better.

Comment: As Kate says: Could mean that you were hot when you tested the tea. **I feel/felt used like this** is possible. It's a way of saying that you feel/felt exploited in some manner!

Answer (score 1):

- "I could feel that the tea was hot." (Kate Bunting) This usage of "feel" would connote physical touch.
- "I felt that the tea was hot." This usage of "feel" would connote more of an emotional judgment or opinion, as Ronald Sole mentioned.